# PyTorch plot loss curve

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I am new to PyTorch and i am trying to plot the loss curve of my training.

I use the first model (matrixfactorizaton) of this page with the movielens dataset. They say that they achieve a RMSE of 0.66, however my plot looks pretty weird.
https://blog.fastforwardlabs.com/2018/04/10/pytorch-for-recommenders-101.html

I also normalized the ratings between [0,1] like described. My code looks as follows:

```
index = 0
running_loss = 0
avg_loss = 0
loss_values = []
for user, item in zip(users, items):
    # get user, item and rating data
    # rating = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([ratings[user, item]]))
    rating = normalize(rating_values[index])
    rating = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([rating]))
    user = Variable(torch.LongTensor([int(user)]))
    item = Variable(torch.LongTensor([int(item)]))

    index += 1
    # predict
    prediction = model.predict(user, item)
    loss = loss_fn(prediction, rating)

    print(loss)

    running_loss += loss.item() / len(users)
    avg_loss += loss.item()
    loss_values.append(running_loss)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # backpropagate
    loss.backward()

    # update weights
    optimizer.step()

avg_loss = avg_loss / len(users)
print("avg loss: " + str(avg_loss))
plt.plot(loss_values)
plt.show()
```

[normal model of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zx5a.png)

[small adaption to the model. i applied the hardsigmoid function before returning the prediction, because i thought something in the model is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJh17.png)

I have read that i have to do something with the batch size but I don't know how. So i think something is wrong in my computation than with the model? The average loss sometimes outputs values close to the 0.66 RSME.

Comment: So just to be sure, your plots are the loss as a function of the epoch ? The first plot is when you copy-paste the code from the tutorial, and the second plot is with your own custom model ? Why don't they have the same x-axis ? Why is one going to 100 times higher abscissas ? Why do your loss plots diverge toward infinity ? Also, what is your normalize function ? In this context I thnk "normalizing" the ratings means dividing by 5 to make them in [0,1]. And finally, Variable is deprecated : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated

Comment: I don't have considered epochs yet. In the end i want to have the loss curve for all epochs aggregated. How can I compute that? The first plot is with 1000 user ids and item ids as input with an adaption to the model which applies the hardsigmoid function to the output. The second plot is for 10000 user and item ids with the model on the webpage.

Comment: I don't know why it goes to infinity, that's why I asked what's wrong with the computation.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of your `optimizer` and `loss_fn` in the code sample ?

Comment: @trialNerror: I declared it exactly like in the tutorial:                                                    loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-6)